# How do you beat Azazel in Tekken 6?

Tags: tekken-6

I'm trying to beat Azazel, in Tekken 6 for the PlayStation 3. Is there a secret to beating him? Does he have any weaknesses? I'm playing with Christie Monteiro.

Comment: Maybe a weird question, but everything I find about Azazel is tekken 6, so are you sure it is tekken 4? [List of Tekken characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Tekken_characters#Introduced_in_Tekken)

Comment: To further support @Daniel, Tekken 4 is a PlayStation 2 title.

Comment: I can confirm that Tekken 4 has no Azazel. There are no special bosses on Tekken 4. Tekken 5's special boss is Jinpachi. Tekken 6 is Azazel. It's a misstag

Comment: I've made the relevant fixes, as I believe the intention is obvious. OP had only stated that they were playing Tekken 4. Frank added the tag in a tag cleanup, as OP had originally used the tag [tag:tekken].

Comment: Did not play Tekken 6 for a big while now but I remember this boss is pretty frustrating. I think I kicked his ass with Lars doing the airborne combo. all the time. You have to have a great defense.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your best bet is to use a jump kick to knock him down, then back away a little bit. If you don't back up, his attack upon teleporting will hit you and chop of quite a chunk of your health. [Detailed description on this method is at the third post](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/tekken-6-a/29234-easy-way-defeat-azazel.html). This method will take some practice I believe, but it's a good way of going at it.

Or you could try to defend his attacks and when he has completed his attacks: hit him. Keep doing this until he is gone. (As said in the first post of the link above).

You could also set the round limit to 1 if you haven't already done so. That way, if you  manage to beat him you won't have to do it once more.

Hope this helps!